# Cookies in react native when used with firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Does cookies are stored in react native apps when used with firebase?

Answer (score 1):

When running on React Native, Firebase Authentication uses `AsyncStorage` to store the user data.